# Jenkins TestLink plugin option to update build custom fields

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, testlink

In TestLink plugin options we can provide the build name but not build specific custom field values. See below the screeshot of available TestLink plugin options:

Perhaps there should be a "Build Custom Fields" input.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain bit about your requirement? Its not much clear what you are asking.

Comment: So TestLink allows addind custom fields to builds. They are visible when we manually open a create build form. But for automation there is no API in the XML RPC. Fixed it by modifying XML-RPC. GitHub PRs https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api/pull/71, https://github.com/jenkinsci/testlink-plugin/pull/23 and https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/pull/47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this feature is actually not implemented in TestLink XML-RPC, Jenkins TestLink Plugin and underlying TestLink Java API. Hence implemented this feature with team here: [TestLink Java API change](https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api/pull/71) [TestLink plugin changes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/testlink-plugin/pull/23) [TestLink XML-RPC](https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/pull/47)